# Segmentation fault when function returns

Tags: c++

I'am a beginner in c++, and i started to write a very basic c++ program:

```
class Solution {
    public:
    vector<string>  fct(vector<string>& list1);
};

vector<string> Solution::fct(vector<string>& list1)
{
   vector<string>::iterator it;
   //vector<string> *ret = new vector<string>;
   for (it=list1.begin();
     it!=list1.end();
     it++)
    {
        cout<<(*it)<<endl;
    }
    //return(*ret); /*This resolved the problem*/
}
```

A call to the function `fct` causes a segmentation fault when `fct` returns:

```
int main()
{
Solution s;
vector<string> list1;

list1.push_back("X");
list1.push_back("Y");
list1.push_back("Z");

s.fct(list1);
}
```

- when i change the return type of `int` there is no problem.
- returning `vector<string>` from `fct`has resolved the problem as well.

I am asking for an explication of this behaviour.

Comment: Step 1 is to drop your code into a debugger and find out why.

Comment: A) You're leaking that vector B) theres no reason to `new` that at all... C) That function is supposed to return something, not doing that is asking for trouble (does that even compile?)

Comment: Not returning a value in a function that's supposed to should be a compile error. Also `list2` does not have a declaration, which is problematic. Are you sure this code compiles?

Comment: What is the type of list2?

Comment: Where is declaration of list2. You are saying that the return type of fct is vector<string> but ain't returning that. And then collecting in list2.

Comment: `list2` is `vector<string> list1` (i missed the declaration when copying), i will edit the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Omitting the `return` statement from a function whose return type is not `void` is cause for undefined behavior.

> when i change the return type of `int` there is no problem.

That's a valid form of undefined behavior. It can be considered lucky/unlucky depending on how you view it. I consider it unlucky since the problem remains hidden.

> returning `vector<string>` from `fct` has resolved the problem as well.

That's the correct way to implement a function that's supposed to return a `vector<string>`.

Answer (score 0):

In line:

```
 list2 = s.fct(list1);
```

You are assigning a value to 'list2'. So you must return a compatible type from function 'fct()'. Since you are returning incompatible type, hence it is causing segmentation fault.
**Note** If you don't return a value from a function and function return type is int then it returns any int value.

Comment: No, it doesn't just *return any int value*, the `int` return type case is undefined behavior as well, and if you're lucky it too will crash.

Comment: list2 is vector<string> list1 (i missed the declaration when copying), the problem comes from " Omitting the return statement from a function whose return type is not void " as mentioned by @R Sahu